# Недопустимая лексема "!=" в объявлении класса, структуры или интерфейса

Tags: c#, лямбда-выражение

Помогите исправить код в C#. Дело в том, что он написан для VS2017, а у меня стоит VS2013 и .NET Framework 4.5.2, соответственно я так предполагаю, что не поддерживается новый синтаксис. Код такой:

```
protected List<RectangleItem> ActualItems =>
    this.ItemsSource != null ? this.actualItems : this.Items;
```

Ругается на != и :

Я новичок в C# и не совсем понимаю как лучше переписать.

Answer (score 5):

Как я понимаю это у вас get-only свойство, попробуйте так

```
protected List<RectangleItem> ActualItems
{
   get 
   {
       if (this.ItemsSource != null) return this.actualItems;
       return this.Items;
   }
}
```

Comment: Вроде скомпилировалось

Comment: А можете еще подсказать как переписать статический класс. Ругается на "Недопустимая лексема "=" в объявлении класса, структуры или интерфейса" :          public static class InterpolationAlgorithms
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Canonical spline, also known as Cardinal spline.
        /// </summary>
        public static IInterpolationAlgorithm CanonicalSpline { get; } = new CanonicalSpline(0.5);     
    }

Comment: @DHel полагаю, что это уже отдельный вопрос